# Apache Beam - Bigquery Upsert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-dataflow

I have a dataflow job which splits up a single file into x number of records (tables). These flow in to bigquery no problem.

What I found though was there was no way to then execute another stage in the pipeline following the results.

For example

```
# Collection1- filtered on first two characters = 95
collection1 = (
    rows    | 'Build pCollection1' >> beam.Filter(lambda s: data_ingestion.filterRowCollection(s, '95'))
            | 'p1 Entities to JSON' >> beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.SplitRowDict(s, '95'))
            | 'Load p1 to BIGQUERY' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    data_ingestion.spec1,
                    schema=parse_table_schema_from_json(data_ingestion.getBqSchema('95')),
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED) # Write to Bigquery
            )

# Collection2 - filtered on first two characters = 99
collection2 = (
    rows    | 'Build pCollection2' >> beam.Filter(lambda s: data_ingestion.filterRowCollection(s, '99'))
            | 'p2 Split Entities to JSON' >> beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.SplitRowDict(s, '99'))
            | 'Load p2 to BIGQUERY' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    data_ingestion.spec2,
                    schema=parse_table_schema_from_json(data_ingestion.getBqSchema('99')),
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED) # Write to Bigquery)
```

Following the above I'd like to run something like the following:

```
final_output = (
    collection1, collection2
       | 'Log Completion' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub('<topic>'))
```

Is there anyway to run another part of the pipeline following the upsert to bigquery or is this impossible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there's no way to do exactly what you asked.  `beam.io.WriteToBigquery` consumes the `pCollection` leaving nothing.

However, it's simple to duplicate the input to `beam.io.WriteToBigquery` in a `parDo` just before you call `beam.io.WriteToBigquery`, and to send copies of your pCollection down each path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340259/7359502) which references  [this sample `doFn` from the docs](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/multiple_output_pardo.py)

Comment: Ok - thanks for that. I'll have a look at splitting the outputs so to retain a pcollection after the upsert.